# How many pyrophosphate groups are released during dinucleotide formation?

Tags: biochemistry, nucleic-acids

I can't seem to fathom how a dinucleotide is formed.

My textbook says that initially both nucleotides have 3 phosphate groups before the join but the formation releases only one pyrophosphate [image: look at this]

If dinucleotide formation releases only one pyrophosphate, where did the two phosphates of the upper nucleotides go?

Also does this mean it releases 2 pyrophosphates? How many pyrophosphate are released during trinucleotide formation?

Comment: I’ll answer your question if you 1. Give title, author and publication date of your textbook, 2. The title of the chapter and section from which this picture is taken — DNA replication I presume, in prokaryotes or eukaryotes or doesn’t say.? 3. Finish reading the [Tour] — which we can tell you haven’t yet.